# MailMessage to MIME String

Tags: c#, mime, mailmessage

I've followed a few StackOverflow posts about how to convert MailMessage to a MIME String. So far, I just can't get it to work. I've gotten around all the errors and specifics with .NET 4.5 but for some reason my string is empty and my stream length is always 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Call to Function:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("from@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "Test", "Test");
Console.WriteLine(ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(message));
```

Function Code:

```
    private static string ConvertMailMessageToMemoryStream(MailMessage message)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
        Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        ConstructorInfo mailWriterConstructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(flags, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
        object mailWriter = mailWriterConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
        MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", flags);
        sendMethod.Invoke(message, flags, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        MethodInfo closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", flags);
        closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, flags, null, new object[] { }, null);
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: why you trying to load MailWriter assembly at runtime?)

Comment: As far as I could tell from research, this is the only way to extract the raw mime text from the built in MailMessage class. From my understanding, the way this works is that there is a private method within mail message that allows us to save it as raw format into a stream but since it's private and not exposed by Microsoft the only way to invoke it is through reflection.

Comment: An alternative would be to use [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/). That has easy methods for writing to streams

Comment: You might have to seek the stream to beginning before reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to seek the stream to the beginning before reading it.
`stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`
The `sendMethod` leaves the pointer at the end so you cant read anything from it.